# AngularJS $stateParams - Access Nested JSON Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I've used stateparams in my single-page angular app to pass data from one state to another, which works, but I need to be able to also pass data into this new state from an array within the top-level object that I've already accessed the data for.

An example of my objects:

```
var employees = [
    {
        id: '21101994',
        icon: 'img/portfolioIcon.png',
        iconAlt: 'N C Image',
        title: 'Mr',
        firstName: 'N',
        lastName: 'C',
        dateOfBirth: '21/10/1994',
        niNumber: 'JZ123456D',
        jobTitle: 'Web Developer',
        department: 'Development',
        joinDate: '18/04/2017',
        leaveDate: '18/04/2017',
        email: 'example@mail.com',
        phonePrimary: '07123 456789',
        phoneSecondary: '07123 456789',
        menu: 'NCMenu',
        employeePayments: [
            {
                id: 1,
                code: 'TEST',
                paymentType: '',
                hours: '',
                zeroiseHours: false,
                partPay: false,
                rate: '',
                employerPercentage: '',
                pay: '',
                paidPer: '',
                fromDate: '',
                sequence: '',
                employerPension: '',
                csaReference: '',
                suspend: false,
                netToGross: false,
                requiredTotal: '',
                paidToDate: '',
                protectedNet: '',
                arrearsCarried: ''
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                code: 'TEST',
                paymentType: '',
                hours: '',
                zeroiseHours: false,
                partPay: false,
                rate: '',
                employerPercentage: '',
                pay: '',
                paidPer: '',
                fromDate: '',
                sequence: '',
                employerPension: '',
                csaReference: '',
                suspend: false,
                netToGross: false,
                requiredTotal: '',
                paidToDate: '',
                protectedNet: '',
                arrearsCarried: ''
            },
        ]
    },
```

I have passed in data like the employee ID, names etc, but how can I pass in data from their employeePayments array so that I can show repeat the details of each of these in a table?

What I've tried for my stateparams in app.js:

```
.state('employees/employeeDetails', {
        url: '/employees/employeeDetails/:employeeId/:icon/:iconAlt/:title/:firstName/:lastName/:dateOfBirth/:niNumber/:jobTitle/:department/:joinDate/:leaveDate/:email/:phonePrimary/:phoneSecondary/:employeePayments',
        templateUrl: 'pages/employees/employeeDetails.html',
        params: {
            employeeId: null,
            icon: null,
            iconAlt: null,
            title: null,
            firstName: null,
            lastName: null,
            dateOfBirth: null,
            niNumber: null,
            jobTitle: null,
            department: null,
            joinDate: null,
            leaveDate: null,
            email: null,
            phonePrimary: null,
            phoneSecondary: null,
            employeePayments: null
        },
        controller: 'employeeDetailsController'
    })
```

employeeDetailsController:

```
app.controller('employeeDetailsController', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, $document, employeesService) {
$scope.employeeId = $stateParams.employeeId;
$scope.icon = $stateParams.icon;
$scope.iconAlt = $stateParams.iconAlt;
$scope.title = $stateParams.title;
$scope.firstName = $stateParams.firstName;
$scope.lastName = $stateParams.lastName;
$scope.dateOfBirth = $stateParams.dateOfBirth;
$scope.niNumber = $stateParams.niNumber;
$scope.jobTitle = $stateParams.jobTitle;
$scope.department = $stateParams.department;
$scope.joinDate = $stateParams.joinDate;
$scope.leaveDate = $stateParams.leaveDate;
$scope.email = $stateParams.email;
$scope.phonePrimary = $stateParams.phonePrimary;
$scope.phoneSecondary = $stateParams.phoneSecondary;
$scope.employeePayments = $stateParams.employeePayments;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case. I did something similar, I didn't use 'params' inside the state object. But I had to use $rootScope instead of $scope for it to work.

Comment: Are you using ui-router for routing? Have you managed to solve the issue yet?

Comment: I am using ui-router for angular1.x, yes. And no, I have not solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For terms of simplicity, let's assume that we want to pass id, title and employeePayments using `$stateParams`.

In state definition:

```
.state('employees/employeeDetails', {
    url: '/employees/employeeDetails/',
    templateUrl: 'pages/employees/employeeDetails.html',
    params: {
        id: null,
        title: null,
        employeePayments: []
    },
    controller: 'employeeDetailsController'
})
```

And in your controller:

```
app.controller('employeeDetailsController', function($scope, $state, 
    $stateParams) {
    $scope.id = $stateParams.id;
    $scope.title = $stateParams.title;
    $scope.employeePayments = $stateParams.employeePayments;
    //...
}
```

So, I think you have to change url and employeePayments definition in params object.

And of course, finally you have your `state.go()` event:

```
$state.go('employees/employeeDetails', {
        id: employees.id,      
        title: employees.title,                              
        employeePayments: employees.employeePayments
    }, {
        reload: true, 
        notify: true
    }
);
```

First argument of `state.go()` is the state where we want our application to go, followed by an object of our state params and finally by some options. You can take a more detailed look [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options).

Comment: I haven't used state.go before. If the employee is clicked on on the 'employees list' page, does this go in the employeesList controller?

Comment: First argument of `state.go()` is the state where we want our application to go, followed by an object of our state params and finally by some options. You can take a look [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options).

Comment: No, I mean where is the actual state.go function placed? In which file? App.js / controller / service etc...

Comment: If the employee is clicked in `employees list` page, `state.go` should be placed in employeesListController.

Comment: Okay, I will try that

Comment: Adding the state.go function to the employees list controller doesn't work. All employees are removed from the ng-repeat list and 'employees' is referring to an undefined employees variable

Comment: Have you put `state.go()` in handling appropriate event, eg. doubleclick an employee in the list? Or have you put it simple in the controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155259/discussion-between-nick-and-lzagkaretos).